# Remove page number of image export from Atlas function of a multi-page composition (QGIS 3.6 print composer)

Tags: qgis-3, atlas

I have 2 pages as part of a multi-page composition in the print composer (QGIS 3.6) and for each page an export condition depending on the attribute value of the feature. This means that based on the attribute value of the feature it is decided whether the feature is printed in a vertical format (page 1) or in a horizontal format (page 2). For all features that are exported with the condition that triggers page 2 to be exported, a suffix with page number "2" is added. The file names of the output images therefore look like this:

feat1_name

feat2_name

feat3_name_2

feat4_name

feat5_name_2

etc

I dont' want a suffix to be addded for all images that are produced with the export condition of page 2. Is there a way to do this with the Atlas function of QGIS3.6?

Answer (score 1):

Many solutions IMHO. In the layout 'Atlas' tab, edit the output expression formula :

*Solution 1* :

```
attribute(@atlas_feature, 'my_atlas_layer_field_name')
```

Search the original data in the atlas layer with the `attribute` function and the variable `@atlas_feature`.

*Solution 2* :

```
if(substr(@atlas_pagename, -2, 2) = '_2',
substr(@atlas_pagename, 1, length('feat1_name_2') - 2),
@atlas_pagename)
```

If the variable `@atlas_pagename` finish with `_2`, trim it, otherwise, give the whole pagename.